# How to fix Could not find method implementation() for argument[project':app']

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I import a project from GitHub, then when I run it, 
the problem appears.

> :Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':app']

https://i.loli.net/2019/04/26/5cc30c4714f6a.png

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app')
    //compile project(':app')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Gradle 3.4. Implementation can't be used before Gradle 3.4.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'`

Comment: thank u, but the eeor: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4  appears.

Comment: @code lies You can try creating a new blank project > let it sync > Close Android Studio > copy content from the 'app' folder of your old app to the 'app' folder of the new app > start Android Studio and load the new project.